# Transpose of large csv file

Tags: python, bash, matlab, csv, large-files

I have a large CSV file ~15GB with 1.8 million columns and 5K rows. I need to take a transpose of a file or if there's an efficient way to read the file column by column. Looking for time and memory efficient solutions in python 2.7, bash, or Matlab.

```
CSV structure:

column names increment from f0,f1 to f1800000
each row has 1.8 million enteries with value of either 0 or 1.


---------------------------------------
 f0,f1,f2    .........    ,f1800000
---------------------------------------

 0,0,1       .........    ,0 
 1,0,1       .........    ,1 

 .........
---------------------------------------
```

Comment: What are your specs? Try using generators.

Comment: 1.8*10^6*5000 are 9*10^9 cells. with 15 GB that is less than 2 bytes per cell. what is your data type? ist the file extremely sparse? please add detailed specifications.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check.

Comment: Read 32 rows at a time (each value is one bit), convert to 1,800,000 unsigned integers, write to a binary file. Do this about 156 times. Write a simple program to read all 156 files one integer from each file at a time, convert to csv syntax (add row names if you want), write these lines to the final file.

Comment: that is just 1.125 GByte of data if you use one bit per value. You should be able to hold that in memory. Read 8 rows into 8 arrays and convert that int a single array of bytes, one byte representing a 8 rows of a single column. repeat until you hold all data in 625 arrays. now loop for all columns and write them as rows to a new file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an efficient way to do it, using pandas, processing rows by mini-batches:

```py
import pandas as pd
NCOLS = 1.8e6  # The exact number of columns

batch_size = 50
from_file = 'my_large_file.csv'
to_file = 'my_large_file_transposed.csv'
for batch in range(NCOLS//batch_size + bool(NCOLS%batch_size)):
    lcol = batch * batch_size
    rcol = min(NCOLS, lcol+batch_size)
    data = pd.read_csv(from_file, usecols=range(lcol, rcol))
    with open(to_file, 'a') as _f:
        data.T.to_csv(_f, header=False)
```